# PUBG on Emulators

Tags: android, pubg-battlegrounds

I have downloaded `PUBG.xapk` and installed it on Both **BlueStack** and **Tencent Game Buddy**..

Both takes few minutes on **Starting PUBG Mobile** Screen and show error that `Please give Storage access to app from settings and restart the app.`

How can i fix the error...

I have I3 processor with 4GB Ram and Intel 
HD Graphics 3000...

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used BlueStacks in a while but it will be similar to any other Android device:

1. to Settings
2. Go to Apps
3. Go to PUBG
4. Scroll down to Permissions
5. It will e a switch or a button or something to let you give it Storage permissions. If it fails and asks for any other permissions do the same for them.

Comment: BlueStack is already granted Storage Permission. I have Checked it the way you told me. still getting error.